# iOS: can I read from SQLite database in the background?

Tags: ios

I have an application that is registered for location updates in the background. Whenever the location is updated I need to loop through an `NSMutableArray` of coordinates to see which one is closest to the user.

Sometimes for memory reasons, the phone kills my application (though it's still registered to receive location updates), and along with it my `NSMutableArray` of coordinates.

So whenever a location update comes in, I have to check if my `NSMutableArray` of coordinates is still alive, and if not I would like to re-populate it from an SQLite table.

After running a few tests, it would appear that the re-population of my coordinate array from the SQLite table is not happening, here is my code that runs whenever the location updates:

```
bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask]}];

if(coordArray == nil || coordArray.count == 0)
{
    [self readCoordinatesFromDatabase];
}
else
{
    //Check which coordinate is closest to the user.
}

if(bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Am I not allowed to read from SQLite in this case?

I absolutely need to be able to go through my coordinate array (in the background) whenever a location update occurs, how can I do this even if the application is killed after a period of time??

Comment: Can you show source of readCoordinatesFromDatabase?

Comment: You can definitely run SQLite in a background thread.  However, if you do you need to be sure to synchronize ALL accesses to the DB to prevent a conflict between threads.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249538/1084174

Answer (score 4):

Guessing that you are talking to SQLite directly, there is no reason why you cant run it in the background.  Are you writing the C code directly to talk to SQLite or are you using a library?

However, if you are having memory issues, maybe you should leave the coordinates in SQLite instead of loading them all into memory?

Or perhaps switch over to Core Data which will help dramatically with the memory issue and reduce the amount of code you are writing to access the data.

Storing the data in SQLite and using the database to find the close coordinates is going to be far more efficient than looping through an array every time a new location comes in.

### Update 1

If your application is not in the front it will get terminated eventually.

If you are using background location updates then the OS will try and keep you running but that is not guaranteed.

If you are a bad citizen with memory you **WILL** be terminated. Keeping the data on disk instead of in memory will help in every way possible. It will reduce your memory, keep you in good status with the OS and increase your chances of your app running in the background.

Don't keep the data in memory, keep it on disk.  Profile your app to keep its memory consumption as close to zero as possible.

Comment: I am only using libsqlite3.0.dylib, and my coordinates are stored in an SQLite table. Whenever my array dies due to the phone killing my application I need to bring it back.

Comment: You need to solve the memory problem and you can do that by **not holding all the data in memory**.  Use SQLite for what it is for. Store the data in SQLite, search against SQLite and your app won't crash due to memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even if I solve the memory problem isn't it still possible that my application get suspended? And aren't suspended applications susceptible to termination if they are not used for a while? I have to be sure that my application is never terminated for any reason, whether it be a memory problem in the app itself or the OS killing the application because it's not being used.

Comment: You can't prevent iOS from terminating applications. As soon as the user launches a game, for example, most non-foreground stuff will be evicted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile your own SQLite using the amalgamation source at http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

   a. Add `sqlite3.c` to your project and add the compiler flag `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1` (under Build Phases > Compile Sources)

   b. Create a table using RTree using something similar to `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE location_index USING rtree(id, minX, maxX, minY, maxY)`  You can put all your locations into the `location_index` and perform geospatial queries on your database to get out the locations within a range of the user location. For more info on using R*Tree in SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html

   c. As Marcus says, avoid keeping all your points in memory. Don't keep them in an array. Don't loop through them. Keep them in the **database**, query for them using using the `location_index` table, and convert them back into objects if/as necessary.
2. Use FMDB as a SQLite wrapper, specifically using FMDatabaseQueue so your database access can be queued (safely accessed by way of more than one thread) and you can use GCD to convert results from SQLite into objects on the fly *but not on the main thread*.  https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb
3. You can't "be sure that my application is never terminated for any reason." Users can terminate your app (e.g. double tap the home button, tap red circle) and if you're a bad citizen, the OS should have the right to terminate your app. Don't be a bad citizen, keep your memory overhead as low as possible.

Answer (score -1):

All SQLite calls must be made from the same thread. You can find an example here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite

*EDIT* the calls must be synchronized as explained below.

Comment: Untrue.  You simply must be careful to synchronize the database, keeping it locked across the entire duration of a given transaction.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more accurate. The calls must be from the same queue.

Comment: Also untrue.  Who uses a queue?

Comment: From my understanding, if you don't specify one, then you are using the main queue. If it is untrue that SQLite must be from the same thread AND queue, then why do calls need to be synchronized?

Comment: You don't understand synchronization.  Yes, there are queues at use inside iOS, and always dispatching from a given task-level queue will guarantee synchronization (because only one task would be used), but that is not necessary for synchronization.  All that's necessary for synchronization is that you *somehow* assure that two separate threads can't go against the DB at the same time (with "same time" including the entire duration of "transactions").  (Plus some hairy but usually covered-by-default details about cache synchronization.)